# SSAS MDX datepart iso_week

Tags: ssas, mdx, week-number, datepart

In T-SQL I can retrieve ISO week number using dateprat function:

```
 select datepart(iso_week, sysdatetime())
```

Is there an equivalent in MDX? I have troubles to find it.
I can retrieve number of week in MDX e.g. like this:

```
with member Measures.Test as (Format(now(), "yyyy") + cstr(datepart("ww", now())))
select  Measures.Test on columns
from    MyCube
```

But how about iso_week? 
Thanks,
Petr

Comment: No idea.  The normal way to do this is to make iso_week a column in your time dimension table.

Comment: Tab Alleman: It is there. But now I need to retrieve some data since the begining until current week. And there is no current week indicator in the dimension. Is there a way to retrieve current ISO week number without adding current ISO week indicator into the Date dimension?

Comment: @Petr make the hierarchy visible so that you can see it when surfing the cube

Comment: @whytheq: the week hierarchy is visible, with correct iso week numbers. (There is no hierarchy Year - Week - Day though). I need to write a MDX query for a report, containing all weeks until the current ISO week. I struggle to find correct current ISO week member. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an "ISO Week" attribute you said?

Comment: @SouravA: yes, there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Iso_week] AS Datepart("ww",NOW()-WeekDay(NOW(),2)+4,2,2)
SELECT [Measures].[Iso_week] ON 0
FROM [Some_cube]
```

More help here: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_ISO_weeknummer_en.html

Comment: This looks very promising. Do you use this approach? Is the formula reliable? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I actually use this approach and I never had any problems with it. I have made some additional tests with the dates like `2016-01-03` and `2016-01-04` and I have compared with SQL's `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [DATE])` and it shows correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the comment

> I need to write a MDX query for a report, containing all weeks until the current ISO week

You can try the below:

```
with member 
Measures.CurrentWeek as cstr(datepart("ww", now()))

member 
WeekValue AS [Date].[Week].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE

select  
Measures.dummymeasures 
ON 0,
[Date].[Week].[Week].MEMBERS HAVING WeekValue <= Measures.CurrentWeek 
ON 1
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE ([Date].[Year].&[2016])
```

Comment: I do something similar. But the tricky part is this: datepart("ww", now()). It does not return current ISO week number.